# File explorer (windows) keeps crashing after enabling and disabling Hyper-v

Tags: windows, hyper-v, microsoft-file-explorer

i have enabled the hyper-v feature because a program requiered it but after a while windows keept crashing so i disabled this feature, after disabling it, the File Explorer of windows keeps bugging out or crashing.

i haven't tried anything as i don't know.